# My comment fields don't show Placeholder text

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website in which comment fields don't show place holder text. It has 4 fields. one each for Name, email address, website and comment.
The first 3 fields have no place holder text due to which it is dificult to identify which field is for which thing. Here is a piece of code that I found in the comments.php file and I believe this is what is causing the problem.

Any helps to fix my problem?

```
$fields = array(
    'author' => '<div class="comment-left pull-left">
                        <p class="input-block">
                            <label for="comment_name" class="required">'.__('Name',  kopa_get_domain()).' <span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" id="comment_name" name="author" class="valid">
                        </p>',
    'email' => '<p class="input-block">
                            <label for="comment_email" class="required">'.__('Email',  kopa_get_domain()).'<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" id="comment_email" name="email" class="valid">
                        </p>',
    'url' => '<p class="input-block">                                                
                            <label for="comment_url" class="required">'.__('Website',  kopa_get_domain()).':</label>
                            <input type="text" name="url" class="valid" id="comment_url">                                                
                        </p>
                    </div>',
);
```

Comment: They do not have placeholder text because they have not been made to have it... it is just plain HTML; what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Comment fields don't have placeholders by default.

Using the code posted in your question it would be easy to add them in:

```
<input type="text" id="comment_name" name="author" placeholder=" . __( 'Name',  kopa_get_domain() ) . '" class="valid">

...

<input type="text" id="comment_email" name="email" placeholder="' . __( 'Email',  kopa_get_domain() ) . '" class="valid">

...

<input type="text" name="url" class="valid" placeholder="' . __( 'Website',  kopa_get_domain() ) . '" id="comment_url">
```

Your email input should have a type of email too.

Comment: Hey Natah, Thanks for responding. I tried using the placeholder attribute myself but it is not appearing on the site. I think there is something else in the file that is stopping it from appearing there. Here is the complete code of comments.php: http://pastebin.com/i7Bqv2XT